# Android NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, junit

I have an application project with source files:

```
androidsrc/MainActivity.java
androidsrc/ClientSession.java
```

I get this error when I run ClientSessionTest.java from eclipse as an android junit test on an emulator.

I followed the standard Hello, Testing tutorial on the android developers website. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added you classes to manifest?

Comment: They're just standard java files. I shouldn't have to add them to the manifest... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This arose out as a symptom of a different problem. One of my classes didn't compile correctly, as was hidden in my log cat "Class resolved by unexpected DEX" whatever that means...